# Android: Sorry this video can not be played in videoview

Tags: android

I know there are many questions and answer on this, but I went through all, but I could not find any solution, and its almost two months I am again and again encountering this issue of "Sorry this video can not be played".

Here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/booksanimation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my code..

```
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.booksanimation);
    videoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.d4sys.sabaq/" + R.raw.booksanimation));
    videoview.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videoview.requestFocus();
    videoview.start();
```

I do not know what are the problems, sometimes when i place another video with different resolution, that video is played but not all videos are played..
If some video is playing on Tablet, it does not play on small devices,,
what are the issues?

Comment: The problem is that some video files can be played on tablet device but not on the phone? And some videos cannot be played at all?

Answer (score 1):

Have you check the video format? Not all format supported natively by Android
I face similar problem before and in the end i change all mov to mp4

`http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html`